# How to redirect to a certain page after logout from any link

Tags: redirection

Does anyone know how to redirect to a certain page like **mysite.com/message-board-page/23**
from any link, for example from **mysite.com/node/add/message-board/23** or **mysite.com/message-board-page/23**

Currently I am doing like this, but it just works for any link that has $arg = 3

$arg = arg(3);
  ....
  href="/user/logout?destination=message-board-page/'.$arg.'"

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you share all your code? Where are you adding your line $arg =... ?

Comment: case 'user_block':
      $arg = arg(3);
      if (in_array('anonymous user', $user->roles)) {
        $block['content'] = '<div class="block-content">
          <div id="login"><a href="/user/login"> Login </a></div>
        </div>';
        }
      else{
        $block['content'] = '<div class="block-content">
          <div id="logout"><a href="/user/logout?destination=message-board-page/'.$arg.'"> Logout </a></div>
        </div>';
      }
    break;

Comment: Could you share all your code?

Comment: Please, use [edit](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/124418/edit) link. The one under your question, or one directly in my comment, I linked it for you here. Comments are ephemeral, second-class citizens here. If some moderator will delete them, nobody will care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am correct you want the user to to redirect to a certain page say test-page-3 from any page or url after logout.
Enable the Trigger Module. In configuration go to Actions, -- there in Create an advanced action Select Redirect to URL and press Create. Then label it as you want it and in URL add the page URL you want the user to redirect. 
Then go to Structures and Select Triggers,  here select USER Tab in Top Right corner.
Then in Trigger: After a user has logged out , Select the action the action u have created.

Hope that helps and tick if u find it useful.

Comment: Hi samir mankar, Unluckily that I could not find any Trigger module for now. :( , but anyway, thank you for your answer!

Comment: It is already there in Drupal 7. You don't need to download it. Just go to your module its there in the bottom. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  case 'user_block': 
    global $user;
    $arg = arg();
    $ca = count($arg);

    $dest = '';
    if (($ca>=2) && ($arg[$ca-2] == 'message-board-page') && is_numeric($arg[$ca-1])) {
      // We have page, that URL end like next: message-board-page/XXX
      $dest = '?destination=message-board-page/' . $arg[$ca-1];
    }

    if (!$user->uid) { // Checking that user is guest like this more simpler.
      $block['content'] = '
        <div class="block-content"> 
          <div id="login">
            <a href="/user/login"> Login </a>
          </div> 
        </div>'; 
    } 
    else { 
      $block['content'] = '
        <div class="block-content"> 
          <div id="logout">
            <a href="/user/logout' . $dest . '"> Logout </a>
          </div> 
        </div>'; 
    } 
    break;
```